# Dragging Element Inside A Div

Tags: javascript, html

I Have been trying to fix this issue but did not succeed.

I have an element inside a div and i am making that element draggable but when i drag it moves too fast and also does not moves with the cursor i have no idea why. I also have tried the same with an element outside that div on body it works completely fine.

Calling Function:

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown',dragClass.mousedown);
```

Drag Class:

```
class drag{
 constructor(){}

 drag(e){
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();

  pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
  pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;

  element.style.top = (element.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
  element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  element.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
 }

 mousedown(e){
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
  if(e.target == element){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    element.style.cursor = 'grab';

    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = dragClass.closeDrag;
    document.onmousemove = dragClass.drag;
  }
 }

 closeDrag(){
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
  element.style.cursor = 'default';
 }

}
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
 }

 .element{
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   outline: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 4;
 }
```

Comment: Are you certain you're adding only a single listener?

Comment: Yes , i remove it with removeEventListner function.

Comment: why dont you use drag events instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent

Comment: Please, please make `container` and `element` class properties :-)

Comment: @ducmai because i can not achieve what i am trying to with those.